# Get product of items in list C# linq

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I have a list with people with integerIds who share Tokens I am trying to get the products of each pair of friends id numbers. so friend id 2 and 4 would result in 8 etc.

```
 var FriendsWhoShareTheMostTokens = FriendsWithTheirSharedTokensAmount.Select(x => new
            {
               FriendIdA = x.FriendTo.FriendID,
               FriendIdB  = x.FriendFor.FriendID,
               SharedCountNumber = x.SharedCount
            })
            .Where(x => x.SharedCountNumber == FriendsWithTheirSharedTokensAmount.Max(y => y.SharedCount))
            .ToList();

// need some code here** 
foreach (var pairOffriendsWhoSharetheMostTokens in FriendsWhoShareTheMostTokens)
{  

}
```

Can I accomplish this with Linq or what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

The answer is simple

```
 var ProductofGreatestTokenSharers = FriendsWhoShareTheMostTokens.Select(x => new
            {
                ProductOfIds = x.FriendIdA * x.FriendIdB
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with your example.

However, if you want to have the id's and the product, and also obtain the highest `SharedCountNumber`.

You can probably just do the following

```
var someResult = someList.Select(x => new
                            {
                                FriendIdA = x.FriendTo.FriendID,
                                FriendIdB = x.FriendFor.FriendID,
                                SharedCountNumber = x.FriendTo.FriendID * x.FriendFor.FriendID    
                            }) // Projection
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.SharedCountNumber) // order the list
                          .FirstOrDefault(); // get the first

if (someResult != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"A : {someResult.FriendIdA}, B : {someResult.FriendIdB}, Product : {someResult.SharedCountNumber}");
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for .